# How to add routes for external scripts in laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.3

Well... I didn't know how to ask question so here is the explanation.

I am using Laravel 5.3 and I have a `register view` it's route are of `Auth::route` I am sending an AJAX request to a different script that is placed in

`public/scripts/` But when it is sent this is the error I am getting

`NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:` this clearly means that there have to be a route given I know but I am confused what to add in the `Route` in `web.php`

My suggestion was `Route::get('/scripts/{scriptname}');`

This didn't work and this is the AJAX request.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#username").blur(function(){
    //$(this).css("background-color", "red");
    var username = $(this).val();
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: '../scripts/check_user_username.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {"username":username},
        success: function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
});
```

check_user_username.php

```
$username = trim(preg_replace('/ +/', ' ', preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/', ' ', urldecode(html_entity_decode(strip_tags($_POST['username']))))));

$stmtcheckusername = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username LIKE ?");
$stmtcheckusername->bind_param("s", $username);
$stmtcheckusername->execute();
$stmtcheckusername->bind_result($username_from_db);
$stmtcheckusername->fetch();
$stmtcheckusername->close();

echo $username_from_db;
```

What I am doing is that when username is entered and user goes to different textbox then it checks whether the username is already in the database or not.

Comment: Why not put the contents of `'../scripts/check_user_username.php'` in a Controller method?

Comment: I am totally new in Laravel. I can send the data but retrieving it would be a difficult task for me

Comment: I suggest you read up on Request and Response lifecycle. I dont think you can or should use Laravel without understanding the basics first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This guy has given a detail to how to send AJAX request to controller

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41853301/how-to-add-routes-for-external-scripts-in-laravel`

Comment: No on is going to write you whole method!